# Open multiple URLs successively in WebBrowser control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ui-thread

I'm trying to make a "rotator" on a form that cycles through a series of urls and displays the url in the `WebBrowser` control.  The following code displays my form, but the form remains white/blank and then the last url in the array appears after a while.  When I put a `MessageBox` in-between each url, to create a stop, it works and each url appears.  I've tried putting a `Sleep` in place of the `MessageBox`, but that didn't work.  I've also tried increasing the `Sleep` time, but that didn't work either.  How can I make it work correctly?

```
Sub Rotate()

    Dim Urls() As String = {"www.stackoverflow.com", "www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"}
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    Form3.Show()

    Do Until counter = 3

        Form3.WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        Form3.WebBrowser1.Navigate(Urls(counter))           
        'MessageBox.Show("Next")
        counter = counter + 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) after changing the URL so that the control gets the chance to redraw itself.
However, a better approach would be to use a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) which fires every 2 seconds and then change the URL in the event handler so that your UI keeps responsive.
For example setup a new field `myTimer` in your form, init it in your form's loading event and in the `Tick` event you call your `Rotate` method. As `Rotate` is now called several times, we have to move the `counter` variable out of the method and make it a field so that we keep its value between the invocations. I usually write C# so hopefully I did not make some typos below :)

```
Private WithEvents myTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
Private counter As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' ... your existing code ...
    counter = 0
    myTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    myTimer.Interval = 2000
    myTimer.Enabled = True
    myTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub myTimerTick() Handles myTimer.Tick
    Rotate()
End Sub

Sub Rotate()
    Dim Urls() As String = {"www.stackoverflow.com", "www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"}
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Urls(counter))           
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter > 3 Then myTimer.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  The first approach you suggested works if I don't try to open a url.  For example if I replace "Form3.WebBrowser1.Navigate(Urls(counter))" with "Label1.Text = Urls(counter)", the label changes as expected.  For "Navigate" however, it still only shows the last url.  Also could you give an example of  your second suggestion?

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Your solution worked.  Thanks!  I made some minor adjustments and posted my answer.